# NGINX proxy_pass aplicação para raiz site

Tags: nginx

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Tenho um servidor com docker swarm funcionando em produção, onde meu nginx está fazendo o papel de proxy reverso para microserviços. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, mas sempre me deparo com o seguinte problema com o nginx.

Preciso que uma aplicação (como jenkins ou zanata por exemplo) caiam na raiz do meu site, como abaixo:

```
server {
server_name myapp.com
listen 80;

location / {
proxy_pass http://ipservidorjenkins/jenkins/;
}
}
```

acima é só um exemplo.. sempre que eu tento fazer um proxy_pass para um endereço que tenha URN (no caso /jenkins), da falha, no casso ou dá 404, ou em alguns casos não carrega CSS e javascript.

Alguém já fez esse tipo de configuração sem ter que adicionar o /jenkins na location? A ideia é acessar myapp.com e cair no http://ipservidorjenkins/jenkins

Obrigado!

Comment: Você tem algum outro `location`? Quando você define um `location` para configurações de caches, por exemplo, o `proxy_pass` do `root` não funciona. Ex: https://pastebin.com/0q8M773n

Comment: Olá Valdeir, eu só tenho essa location, nesse caso eu a minha raiz seria o proxy_pass para o servidor do Jenkins. Eu teria que adicionar a configuração que você passou (pe?g|gif|css|js|png|webp) para o servidor do Jenkins também?

Comment: Olá! Você consegue passar o IP real do cliente através desse nginx? Ou seja, consegue informar o IP verdadeiro para aplicação cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Oi! Ele apresenta erro, pois, não foi passado o parâmetro `--prefix=/jenkins` , ao iniciar o Jenkins. 
Veja este [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=66847445#content/view/66847445) como referência.